# How to pass Javascript dynamic array to d3 dimple chart

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, charts, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to build a chart using javascript running in the browser.  The script pulls data from AWS DynamoDB, before using dimple and d3 to construct a chart in the browser.  I am looping through the results of a database scan and adding data to the array using array.push().  The result is that the chart axes are drawn but no data points or lines appear at all.

The aim is to plot a line graph / chart with clientTimeStamp on the x axis and airQ on the y axis.

Here is the javascript code, which is placed within  tags in my simple HTML page:

```
//Connect to Dynamo via Cognito Unauthenticated
function getDynamoData() {
  var db, tableName, creds;
  var d3Data = [];

  creds = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: "eu-west-1:xxxxxx" //place cognito Unauthenticated ID pool here
  });

  AWS.config = new AWS.Config({
    region:"eu-west-1",
    credentials: creds
  });

  db = new AWS.DynamoDB();
  tableName = "xxxxxxxx"; //insert your own table name here

  db.scan(params = {TableName: tableName}, function(err, data) {
    data = data.Items;
    //Sort the data by timestamp
    data.sort(function(a, b) {
      return parseFloat(a.clientTimeStamp.N) - parseFloat(b.clientTimeStamp.N);
    });

    data.forEach(function(item){
      d3Data.push({"timeStamp":item.clientTimeStamp.N, "airQ":item.airQ.N});
      console.log(item.airQ.N);
      console.log(item.clientTimeStamp.N);
      console.log(item.clientVer.S);
    })
  })
  drawChart(d3Data, "clientTimeStamp", "airQ");
}

// Draw the chart with dimple
function drawChart(chartData, xLabel, yLabel) {
  var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 800, 600);
  var chart = new dimple.chart(svg, chartData);
  chart.setBounds(60,30, 510, 305);
  chart.addCategoryAxis("x", xLabel);
  chart.addMeasureAxis("y", yLabel);
  chart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.line);
  chart.draw();
}

getDynamoData();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to my own question:
Essentially, the call to the drawChart function must be made from within the db.scan function.   I suspect this is because 'data' is not a global variable and thus its scope is limited to the db.scan function.  After that, a couple of minor changes were required to get the date correct displayed on the x axis.

Corrected code is as follows:

```
//Connect to Dynamo via Cognito Unauthenticated
function getDynamoData() {
  var db, tableName, creds, data;
  var d3Data = [];

  creds = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: "xxxxxxxx" //Insert correct Cognito ID pool here
  });

  AWS.config = new AWS.Config({
    region:"eu-west-1",
    credentials: creds
  });

  db = new AWS.DynamoDB();
  tableName = "xxxxxxxxx";  //Insert correct DynamoDB table name

  db.scan(params = {TableName: tableName}, function(err, data) {

    data = data.Items;
    //Sort the data by timestamp
    data.sort(function(a, b) {
      return parseFloat(a.clientTimeStamp.N) - parseFloat(b.clientTimeStamp.N);
    });

    data.forEach(function(item){
      var dateNum = Number(item.clientTimeStamp.N);
      var myDate = new Date(dateNum);
      var strDate = myDate.toISOString();
      console.log("strDate = " + strDate);
      d3Data.push({"clientTimeStamp":strDate, "airQ":item.airQ.N});
    })
    drawChart(d3Data, "clientTimeStamp", "airQ");
  })
}

// Draw the chart with dimple
function drawChart(chartData, xLabel, yLabel) {
  var iso = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ");
  var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 800, 600);
  var chart = new dimple.chart(svg, chartData);
  chart.setBounds(60,30, 510, 305);
  var x = chart.addTimeAxis("x", xLabel,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ","%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
  x.timePeriod = d3.time.minutes;
  x.timeInterval = 10;
  chart.addMeasureAxis("y", yLabel);
  chart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.line);
  chart.draw();
}

getDynamoData();
```